# Implementing ReadKey() on a TextReader

Tags: c#, textreader

I have a class that accepts input via a TextReader and will allow the class to receive input from either the console or from a text box.

The following is a very basic example of what I'm trying to do:

```
using System.IO;

class TestReader()
{
    public TextReader CurrentStream { get; }

    public void SetInputStream( TextReader reader)
    {
        Reader = reader;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        TestReader rdr = new TestReader();
        rdr.SetInputStream(Console.In);

        var input = (char)rdr.CurrentStream.Read();

        Console.WriteLine( "You selected: " + input );

    }
}
```

How do I change the above to implement `ReadKey()` as the `Read()` method in the above example keeps accepting input until the Enter key has been pressed?  I'd like to implement ReadKey() so that it only accepts a single keypress.

Thanks.

** EDIT **

To clarify things further, I am looking to implement ReadKey() without using Console.ReadKey().  I am not sure it's even possible since Google is turning up nothing so far.

Comment: You can't because the text reader is a stream of characters, but a key  (or key combination) may not be a character.

Comment: @DarrenKopp: In that case how does `ReadKey()` do it then? It's now looking likely that I am going to have to implement my own `ReadKey()` method without using Console.ReadKey().

Comment: ReadKey works because it is intercepting the keyboard key press events.

Answer (score 0):

i used

```
     ConsoleKeyInfo info;
     do
     {
        info = Console.ReadKey();
     } while (info.KeyChar != '\n' &&
        info.KeyChar != '\r');
```

to loop until i get an enter press

if you have only input stream or `textBox` you can just do an `if` statement. in case of console use my example, in case of `textBox` read it's text

Comment: That code won't do because you're referencing the `Console` class in your example.  I don't want the class to know anything about the `Console` or `TextBox` implementations as these should be provided by the calling application, whether it'll be a Console or Winforms application.

Comment: @MikeClarke textBox can send it's text and  Console can use the code i gave you and send the text it got, so why not do SetInputStream to receive string?

Comment: The problem is that the `TextReader` class doesn't implement a `ReadKey()` method, and in your example you're using the `Console` class directly, which won't work in a Winforms application.